# vb.ne send email from a shared mailbox

Tags: vb.net, mime

i'm supposed to send an email as customer care from a shared mailbox to several addresses of my company customers.
i'm using mailkit library and i use this code
Code:

```
Dim contenutomail As New MimeKit.BodyBuilder
Dim smtpclient As New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient
 Dim mail As New MimeKit.MimeMessage
 smtpclient.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
 smtpclient.Authenticate("eurostar_italia@mycompany.com", "Aprile22")
 mail.From.Add(New MimeKit.MailboxAddress("", "customeroffice@mycompany.com"))
  For i = 0 To mailinglist.Count - 1
 mail.Bcc.Add((New MimeKit.MailboxAddress("",mailinglist(i).ToString)))
 Next
 contenutomail.TextBody = ""
 contenutomail.HtmlBody = "hello world"
        mail.Body = contenutomail.ToMessageBody
        smtpclient.Send(mail)
        smtpclient.Disconnect(True)
```

the problem is : sent mail are save in MY personal account SENT mailbox instead of shared SENT mailbox.
I don't have any Admin right to modify the office365 sharedmailbox.
can anyone help me ? i don't want to save a copy,i want the mail sent to be saved in the sent shared mailbox
i can't solve it
thanks
fabio

Comment: Not an attempt at answering, but you might want to remove the login details from your post

Comment: you have customeroffice@mycompany.com email and password ? then why not use that email and password for smtpclient.Authenticate instead of using your personal account details. So credential and from address are same.

Comment: customeroffice@mycompany.com is the shared mailbox, eurostar_italia@mycompany.com and Aprile22 are my personal mailbox and moreover authentication id for the shared mailbox. i can't access direct to the customeroffice@mycompany.com.